# SQL assume case sensitive despite ci collation?

Tags: php, sql

In my users table, I have a row with `username = Q`. When I try to log-in as "q" instead, it states the user does not exist, however with "Q" it works as intended. Here's the login check code.

```
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$pahash = crypt($password, $username);
$logcheck = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
        AND password = :pahash
");
$logcheck->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username,
    ':pahash' => $pahash));
```

The collation for pretty much every single column in my database is "latin1_swedish_ci", which is case insensitive. Why is it, then, that it seems to be working as case sensitive?

If it matters, the type for the user column is char(20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `crypt` is not case insensitive.  So the value of `$pahash` is different for the same value of `$password` when the value of `$username` changes from `Q` to `q`.

Comment: Ah, so in either case it passes the `$username` check, but it fails the `$password` check regardless if `$username` is correct or not.

Comment: I could get around my issue by querying the table for the username, and then salting the password with the username grabbed from SQL. If they type "q", it will grab "Q" from the database and things should be well.

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$username = strtolower($username);
$pahash = crypt($password, $username);
$logcheck = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE LOWER(username) = :username
        AND password = :pahash
");
$logcheck->execute(array(
    ':username' => $username,
    ':pahash' => $pahash));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "LIKE" instead of "=" for username:

```
SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username LIKE :username
    AND password = :pahash
```